# Nginx $http_cookie if directive pattern matching

Tags: if-statement, cookies, nginx

So on the Nginx documentation it is a bit unclear but it appears we can use Regex to match anything within the if statement

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if

So i wanted to tweak this to make it so Nginx checks the value of any cookie.

But my following string what should be from my understanding * matching any cookie name and = matching any cookie contents.

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "*=*") {
return 444;
}
```

But i get the error "pcre_compile() failed: nothing to repeat in "*" at "*" in"

What i am trying to achieve is to Have nginx check the cookie like a WAF (web application firewall) to make sure it only contains A-Z uppercase a-z lowercase 0-9 + - _ . my PHP app is Joomla what does these checks too but be useful if i could perform these checks with Nginx too since it could deny the request faster.

EDIT to Show half solved issue / dilemma

```
set $block_cookie_exploits 0;
#If cookie name or contents does not contain the following
if ($http_cookie !~ "[a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\_]=[a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\_]") {
set $block_cookie_exploits 1;
}
#Block the client request
if ($block_cookie_exploits = 1) {
return 403;
}
```

New problem with above configuration is it will return 403 while no cookie is present. And if you put characters in the name or contents of the cookie like {} it does not return 403

Comment: You regex is wrong. ``*`` stand for ``repeat between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible``, but you will need to tell it what to check for.

Comment: So i have to specify the cookie name and the cookie contents ? Their doc shows a pattern matching string being used i don't see why i can't apply the same thing just to make sure it contains only specific characters.

Comment: what do you what to achieve?  make sure that requests without any cookies get a 444 return? Just try to change ``"*=*"`` to ``"[a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\_]*=[a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\_]*"``

Comment: You have to write a regular expression to make it like a WAF. The example i give will have problem since cookie may contain characters like ``: = %``